# how to show result_set images in view with grid order

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I got all the records from the database and passing to the view.
The array of data:

```
Array ( 
  [image_info] => 
     Array ( [0] =>
       Array ( [file_name] => DSC00081.JPG  )
             [1] => 
       Array ( [file_name] => DSC00082.JPG  ) 
             [2] => 
       Array ( [file_name] => DSC00083.JPG )
     )
   )
```

I want to display all the image in the view in the following format
[image: The browser view of images sample]

I want to display the first image in the first column, the second image (if exists in the result set) must be in the second column, likewise it goes on..The fourth image (if exists in the result set) must be in second row..
So far i have tried the following..

```
<section id="services" class="services-section section-global-wrapper">
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">

            <ul>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <?php 
                foreach($image_info as $images)
                { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>upload/<?php echo $images['folder_name'].'/'.$images['file_name'];?>" height="400" alt="Image of second carousel"/>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>  

            </ul>

          </div>

        </div>

</section>
```

I am not able to get what I desire.

Comment: did you check this value `$images['folder_name']`?

Comment: @vel  yeah it is coming ..!

Comment: @Keynes, Check my answer, I think it should work! If not let me know there.

Comment: @Keynes, Can you check with more than 3 values? I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: @ShaunakShukla, I tried with 5 images, but the images are not listing in a desired way as i shown in the image above. I need to have some padding in between as well..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<section id="services" class="services-section section-global-wrapper">
    <div class="container">


            <?php 
            $Inc = 1;
            foreach($image_info as $images){ 
                if($Inc==4 || $Inc==1){ 
                $Inc=1;                     
                echo '<div class="row">';                       
            }
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>upload/<?php echo $images['folder_name'].'/'.$images['file_name'];?>" height="400" alt="Image of second carousel"/>
                </div>  

            <?php 

                $Inc++;
            if($Inc==4){                                            
                echo '</div>';                      
            }
                } 
            ?>

      </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: I am getting the images listed but without proper format as i have indicated in the image above..!

Comment: Is it possible to show with proper css in the grid view?

Comment: It is working perfectly, Both the codes are working..I will edit the answer and post it now with the css link

Answer (score 2):

```
    <section id="services" class="services-section section-global-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
 <?php $i=0;
                    foreach($image_info as $images)
                    { if($i%3==0) { ?>
                <div class="row">
   <?php } ?>  <ul>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">

                        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>upload/<?php echo $images['folder_name'].'/'.$images['file_name'];?>" height="400" alt="Image of second carousel"/>


                </div>  
     </ul>

   <?php if($i%3==2) { ?>
              </div>
 <?php } $i++; } ?>

            </div>

    </section>
```

You need to reposition the loop!

Comment: fine it comes in an order. .. but what if i have a fourth image. will it goes to second row? i didnt give u -ve vote or +ve vote...

Comment: Did you give me -ve?

Comment: Can you try with more than 3 values?

Comment: I tried with 5 values, it wnt to second row, but i did not get the desired look as i mentioned in the image above.. I needed gap between images as well

Comment: OK, but you are getting them in new rows after 3, right?

Comment: yes yes i get in the second row, without proper format

Comment: I forgot to add `<ul>` from your code.. now it is added.. check please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145026/discussion-between-shaunak-shukla-and-keynes).